# Implementing a base class tree with arbitrary amount of child nodes of derived types?

Tags: c++, tree

I want to implement a GPA calculator program with the following structure: A collection of years is a tree of years, a year is a tree of semesters, and a semester is a tree of courses. These types will all be derived from one base class called "Container". Since we dont know how many classes could be contained in a semester, i want to have a vector of pointers to its children so that we can add an arbitrary amount of course nodes. Would the following implementation work?

```
template <typename ContainerType, typename ChildType>
class Container
{
protected:
    // Node class definition.
    class Node
    {
    public:
        ContainerType   data;   // contents of the node.
        vector<Node*>   child;  // links to the node's children.
        // Node constructor functions:
        Node() { }
        Node(const ContainerType &theData) : data(theData) { }
    };
protected:
    Node *current;   // Points to the current node
    Node *parent;    // Points to current node's parent
};
```

Im hoping that every time i add a child node, I can increase the amount of child Node pointers as needed. Is this possible? I have a feeling that since the container's node pointers will point to nodes of different types, that this might cause issues.

Comment: Why don't you use more of polymorphizm? Like, you could use pointers to Container everywhere, since all the types derive from it. Each container-derived type could contain something like `std::list<container*> children` with or without one more pointer to parent. What do you need the Node class for at all?

Comment: These aren’t trees because they’re not **recursive** — you can’t have a semester inside a semester inside a year.  It’s therefore not clear that you even need a template (other than maybe `template<class T> using Children=std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;` for notational convenience — **if** you have a reason to avoid just storing the children directly in a `vector`).